# HTML string parsing using dom

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom

```
<html>

<head>
<?PHP
include('simple_html_dom.php');
?>
<title>

</title>
</head>

<body>
<form name ="form1" method ="POST" ACTION="parser.php">
<input type="text" name="parser1" style="height:200px; width:200pt;"></br></br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"></br></br>
</form>

<?php

$html_str = $_POST['parser1'];

// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html($html_str);
$html->load('
<form name="form1" action="parser.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="parser1">
</form>');

// Get the form action
foreach($html->find('form') as $element) 
   echo $element->action . '<br>';

// Get the input name       
foreach($html->find('input') as $element) 
   echo $element->name . '<br>';
?>
</body>

</html>
```

Here i am trying to enter the html source into the text box `parser1`

I am then catching the data from the textbox using post into a string `html_str`

when i try to parse that string, i start getting errors.

> Fatal error: Call to a member function load() on a non-object in /home/public_html/parser.php on line 24

please help

Answer (score 1):

You have this:

```
$html = file_get_html($html_str);
$html->load('
<form name="form1" action="parser.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="parser1">
</form>');
```

The error message says that `$html` is not an object. `file_get_html()` isn't a builtin function but you appear to be using [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/). Its [API documentation](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual_api.htm#api) says that it returns an object but fails to provide additional info. If we look at the source code:

```
function file_get_html($url, $use_include_path = false, $context=null, $offset = -1, $maxLen=-1, $lowercase = true, $forceTagsClosed=true, $target_charset = DEFAULT_TARGET_CHARSET, $stripRN=true, $defaultBRText=DEFAULT_BR_TEXT, $defaultSpanText=DEFAULT_SPAN_TEXT)
{
    // We DO force the tags to be terminated.
    $dom = new simple_html_dom(null, $lowercase, $forceTagsClosed, $target_charset, $stripRN, $defaultBRText, $defaultSpanText);
    // For sourceforge users: uncomment the next line and comment the retreive_url_contents line 2 lines down if it is not already done.
    $contents = file_get_contents($url, $use_include_path, $context, $offset);
    // Paperg - use our own mechanism for getting the contents as we want to control the timeout.
    //$contents = retrieve_url_contents($url);
    if (empty($contents) || strlen($contents) > MAX_FILE_SIZE)
    {
        return false;
    }
    // The second parameter can force the selectors to all be lowercase.
    $dom->load($contents, $lowercase, $stripRN);
    return $dom;
}
```

... we can see it returns `FALSE` some times:

```
if (empty($contents) || strlen($contents) > MAX_FILE_SIZE)
{
    return false;
}
```

So I'd dare say that your POST field is either empty or too large. You should really check that before calling `->load()`.

**Update:**

The `file_get_html()` function:

> Creates a DOM object from a **file or a URL**.

I guess what you really want is `str_get_html()`:

> Creates a DOM object from a **string**.

Answer (score 0):

It might help if you actually check if the form is submitted or not. You have to check and re-check if the input is valid or not.

```
// check if it's a POST request
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    // check if parser1 is not empty
    if(!empty($_POST['parser1'])) {
        $input = $_POST['parser1'];

        if(filter_var($input, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) { // looks like an URL
            $html = file_get_html($input); // download URL
        } else { // lets assume it's HTML, because it's not an URL
            $html = str_get_html($input);
        }

        // If something goes wrong here, the input is invalid
        if(!empty($html)) {
             // parse DOM document here
        } else {
            // There is something wrong with the input
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: no, the `$html` seems to be not working. How do i solve that part of the problem? I need the user to input the source of the web page into the text box and then i will extract data from that source code.

Comment: yes, the document is not being submitted... how do i go around this and accomplish my target?

Comment: @debal check out my answer again.

Comment: i am getting this new warning 
`Warning: file_get_contents(here is the data that i insert into the text box) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/public_html/simple_html_dom.php on line 75`